# Cannot run Java HelloWorld on MacBook Pro OS Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: java, macos

I have a Mac running Yosemite 10.10.5 on a MacBook Pro and I have the recommended Java version jre.8u91.  I have tried different attempts to run the following simple program, Which I created using TextEdit:

```
public class HelloWorld3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Note: it puts it away as an .rtf file.  There is no .java file option under TextEdit file suffixes.  There are others.
In the Terminal app I type the following:

```
cd ~
Javac HelloWorld3.java
```

and receive the following:

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:documents davidellisrogers$ javac HelloWorld3.rtf
error: Class names, 'HelloWorld3.rtf', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
1 error
Davids-MacBook-Pro:documents davidellisrogers$
```

It has been a year since I used Java with Netbeans on my PC.  I am relatively new to the Mac world.  I suspect the .rtf and have forgotten the annotation parameter from my PC days.

Would appreciate help.

Comment: It needs to be a .java file. Just go to the terminal and type `nano HelloWorld3.java` paste in the code, save it (ctrl+x) and then run the javac command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save as HelloWorld3.java

and run the following command:

javac HelloWorld3.java

java HelloWorld3

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using a WYSIWYG, rich text editor for programming purposes is exactly what's causing the problem here. Try something different such as NetBeans, Eclipse, or Sublime.